# Why does android studio only let me set text (on a button or text view) by chars (and not strings?)

Tags: string, textview, settext

Whether I try to change a textView or a button, why does Android Studio require that I pass only chars and not strings in the setText() method?

Comment: Pretty sure Strings are `CharSequence`s; or at least coercable to `CharSequence`s. Did you try?

Comment: Yes, it works to recast the char sequences into strings.

Comment: But how does one pass a string directly?

Comment: It should work to pass a string directly.

Answer (score 0):

`String`s are automatically converted to `CharSequence`s when necessary (or **are** `CharSequence`s; can't remember. The point is, they're compatible):

```
public class Main {
    public static void testF(CharSequence seq) {
        System.out.println(seq);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        testF("Hello"); // Prints "Hello" 
    }
}
```

This would have been a good thing to try on your own or search for first.